# File extension while searching

Tags: powershell, console

I am trying to get a list of all my files with a specific extension.

```
(...)$_.Extension -eq ".$ext"
```

I read extension from console to script.

My question is how to find any file with an extension of  `.*`?

**Edit:**

Here's the rest of the code:

```
$setOfFolders = (Get-ChildItem -Path D:\ -Directory).name 
Write-host "Set last write date " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline 
$ostZmiana= read-host $exten = read-host "Set extensions " 

ForEach ($f in $setOfFolders) 
{ 
    $saveTofile = "C:\Users\pziolkowski\Desktop\Outs\$f.txt" 
    Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Urzad\Wspolny\$f -Recurse | ? {$_.LastAccessTime -lt $ostZmiana -and $_.Extension -eq ".$exten"} | % {Get-acl $_.FullName} |sort Owner | ft -AutoSize -Wrap Owner, @{Label="ShortPath"; Expression= $_.Path.Substring(38)}} > $saveToFile 
}
```

Comment: You need to add more of your actual code to let people help you to accomplish what you need. There are many ways to do what you're asking for, but is really difficult give you an help starting from your question as is.

Comment: Rest of the code:
$setOfFolders = (Get-ChildItem  -Path D:\ -Directory).name

Write-host "Set last write date "  -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
$ostZmiana= read-host
$exten = read-host "Set extensions "

ForEach ($f in $setOfFolders) {
$saveTofile = "C:\Users\pziolkowski\Desktop\Outs\$f.txt"
Get-ChildItem  -Path D:\Urzad\Wspolny\$f -Recurse | ? {$_.LastAccessTime -lt $ostZmiana -and $_.Extension -eq ".$exten"} | % {Get-acl $_.FullName} |sort Owner | ft -AutoSize -Wrap Owner, @{Label="ShortPath"; Expression= {$_.Path.Substring(38)}} > $saveToFile
}

Comment: Edit your question to add the code, comment is not the place to put in code. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$_.Extension` will see the file as, (in the case of a text file) `.txt`

If `$ext` is currently a valid extension, then `.$ext` would look like `..txt` echoed out.

The easiest way to get a list of files with a specific extension in PowerShell is one of two, really.

C like syntax:

```
$myList
Get-ChildItem |`
    Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.Extension -eq ".txt") { $myList += $_}
    }
```

PowerShell style:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".txt"} | Do stuff
```

To get all files, as most files have an extension, just use Get-ChildItem or GCI or ls. (GCI and LS are aliases for Get-ChildItem).

To get all files with an extension, but not a specific extension:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Extension}
```

This evaluates as a bool, so true or false.

These are off the cuff, but should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks :) but you said how to find specyfic extension but I nedd any (like file.log and file.jpg) file.*

Comment: Update your question then, I will update the answer. Currently you start with `Im trying to get list of files with specific extension.`

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the -filter on Get-ChildItem:

`Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt"`

And you can specifiy recursion too:

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.txt"`

Comment: After testing it appears that for filtering file extensions `-Filter "*.txt"` is a lot faster than `-Include *.txt`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This doesn't actually match the extension. It also matches "Filename.txt-skip" !